# How to api response change

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api

I want to transfer the data into an array and my api response is [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0P8MB.png)

inside api response there is: `locationslist :"[\"Location 2\",\"Location 2\"]"`

How to get a clean response in react Js?

And I am also try a `JSON.parse()` it's give me error

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting error because you are trying to parse JavaScript object using `JSON.parse()`. To fix the issue you need to pass JSON string to the `JSON.parse()` method like following:

```js
const something = {
  locationslist :"[\"Location 2\",\"Location 2\"]"
};

// This code will give error
console.log(JSON.parse(something));

// This will work fine because locationslist
// holds a JSON string
console.log(JSON.parse(something.locationslist));
```

Answer (score 1):

**This should do it just fine:**

```js
const localtionList = "[\"Location 2\",\"Location 2\"]";
console.log(JSON.parse(localtionList))
```